# Polymorphism can't override when using string

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dev-c++

`Polymorphism` in dec C, isn't working with string

I am using `Dev C++ 5.9.2.`

I have a parent class `A`, class `B,C,D,E`.....`extends A` and class `list` is the main class where I use `B,C,D.`

I don't use parent `A` , because i want to reuse constructor A.

The problem as follows

```
class A
{
    public:
    virtual void show(){
            printf("A");
        }
    private:    
    string tokenS;

};

class B :public A
{
    public:
    virtual void show(){
        printf("B:");
       // return 0;
    }
}

class list
{
    public:
        A* getNode(){
           return pta;
        }

        void setNode(B temp){
           this->pta=&temp;
        }
    protected:
    private:
        A *pt1;
};
int main(){
    list ls;
    B b1;
    ls.setNode(b1);
    ls.getNode()->show();
}
```

> if i using `string tokenS`  result :***A***
>
> if i using `char* tokenS`   result :***B:***

I don't understand it, and if I create class and use it , i have the same error

```
class Date
{
   // code
};

class A
    {
        public:
        virtual void show(){
                printf("A");
            }
        private:    
        Date day;

    };

 class B :public A
    {
        public:
        virtual void show(){
            printf("B:");
           // return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `void` functions cannot `return 0;`.

Comment: `void setNode(B temp){
           this->pta=&temp;
        }` is a problem. `this->pta` becomes a dangling pointer as soon as the function returns.

Comment: you can explain more problen , and give me solution . thanks every for answer.

Comment: It's hard to suggest a good fix because it's not really clear what the code is trying to do. Why does `list` keep pointers to objects? Who or what is supposed to own those objects and manage their lifetimes? If the list itself, why does it have pointers rather than the objects? Is it just because of polymorphism? If so, use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: For example: I have class preson and class extend: teacher , farmer ,.... and I have class list to manger person in tower. .And I use "Automatic memory allocation" to manger. If I don't you pointer ,I can't polymorphism.
Code here I reduce to my project , I test in another CPP.
Thanks for answer , I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    void setNode(B temp){
       this->pta=&temp;
    }
```

This sets `pta` to point to `temp`, but `temp` no longer exists when the function ends. Here's on way to fix it and preserve the polymorphism:

```
class A
{
    public:
    virtual void show(){
            printf("A");
        }
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() = 0;
    private:    
    string tokenS;

};

class B :public A
{
    public:
    virtual void show(){
        printf("B:");
       // return 0;
    }
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone()
    {
        return std::make_unique<B>(*this);
    }
};

class list
{
    public:
        A& getNode(){
           return *pt1;
        }

        void setNode(A& temp){
           pt1 = temp.clone();
        }
    protected:
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<A> pt1;
};
int main(){
    list ls;
    B b1;
    ls.setNode(b1);
    ls.getNode().show();
}
```